# How to check which project (.NET Framework Class Library) is set as startup project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, .net-4.8

I've two projects(.NET Framework Class Libraries) in ASP.NET MVC. I'm using visual studio. How do I check which one of these two projects is `set as startup project`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he is bold on his name, the start up project  bold ..
[image]